# How to document dart functions/constructors parameters?

Tags: dart

With dart it is possible to prefix class/function definition by a commentary so that the analyzer will interpret it as documentation:

```
/// Some documentation for [Foo]
class Foo {

}
```

But how can I achieve the same behavior, with parameters instead?

I tried the following:

```
void myFunction(
 /// Some parameter documentation
 String parameter,
) {

}
```

But this doesn't work.

---

However, it seems possible because `dartanalyzer` *do* contain a property on `ParameterElement` for documentation.

Answer (score 4):

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation

Here's the offical Dart language guidelines for documentation best practice. It covers most/all cases and has great examples of do's and don't's.

[This bit](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-square-brackets-in-doc-comments-to-refer-to-in-scope-identifiers) shows the way to include parameters. Basically, wrap the parameters in square brackets and within a sentence explaining it.

Comment: That's not what I'm asking for. I don't want parametrized documentation, but documentation for parameters.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're after then? I have a few apps written in Dart in production, and this is how we do our documentation for the classes and parameters, in accordance with the documentation guidelines I linked.

Explain in prose in the class-level documentation, and then have another smaller /// comment above each parameter.

Comment: I have a quite specific use case. I need documentation for each separated arguments, to then extract them using a custom tool. So a big documentation on the element doesn't work

Comment: @RémiRousselet did you find a way to do it ? Specifically I want to do it for a constructor without resorting to make the properties available on the class too. So no `this.param`. It seems like dart is lacking the functionality of adding the documentation for param then ?

Comment: @RémiRousselet Did you found an answer eventually? This is important when a constructor parameter is transient and not an instance field. And we need documentation for it.

Comment: This is the closest official thing I found: https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/documentation#do-use-prose-to-explain-parameters-return-values-and-exceptions